# Altair map interactive histograms by different time intervals

Tags: python, altair

so lets say I have the following altair plot (from the altair documenation:https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/histogram_responsive.html)

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.flights_5k.url

brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

base = alt.Chart(source).transform_calculate(
    time="hours(datum.date) + minutes(datum.date) / 60"
).mark_bar().encode(
    y='count():Q'
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=100
)

alt.vconcat(
  base.encode(
    alt.X('time:Q',
      bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=30, extent=brush),
      scale=alt.Scale(domain=brush)
    )
  ),
  base.encode(
    alt.X('time:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=30)),
  ).add_selection(brush)
)
```

Which generates the following chart:

[image: identical time scales]

Is it possible to make it so that the bottom histogram is scaled by a different interval (say months) instead:

[image: different time scales]

Or is this something that is very hard to do with Altairs data model?

I cannot simply change the transform to

```
time="month(datum.date) + date(datum.date)"
```

Since this simply results in altair summing the month (say 1) and the day (say 12) together. I have thought about trying to convert this to a unix time stamp and using that, but I would still have the same problem where the scales would display the same values. Is this opperation possible with altair or is there a different recomended approach.

Thank you, I appreciate any advice on resolving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK not creating using timeunits instead of binning the axis, you can have a temporal encoding in the upper plot and an ordinal one for the months in the lower chart:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


source = data.flights_5k.url

brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    y='count():Q'
).transform_calculate(
    month='month(datum.date)'
).properties(
    width=600,
    height=100
)

alt.vconcat(
  base.encode(
    x='hours(date):T',
    color=alt.Color('month:O', legend=None)
  ).transform_filter(
      brush
  ),
  base.encode(
      x='month(date):O',
      color='month:O'
  ).add_selection(
      brush
  )
)
```

[image]

On selection:
[image]

You can use the `detail` instead of `color` encoding if you don't want to show the months in different colors.